# I get a Null Pointer when I add to my edges to my graph (tree)

Tags: java, graph, tree

I had an assignment to create a Kruskal algorithm, which went fine there was a nice tutorial online, but I'm having difficulty trying to add the edges to all of my nodes with the assigned weights. Here is what I'm doing and hopefully you guys can help me out.

#### main function

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maximumVertices = 50;
    Random ran = new Random();


    Graph g = new Graph(maximumVertices);
    for(int i=0; i<maximumVertices-1; i++){
        int weight = ran.nextInt(50);
        int connectedNode = ran.nextInt(10); //the idea here is to create random connections between nodes
        g.addVertex(i);
        g.addBidirectionalEdge(i, connectedNode, weight);
        g.addBidirectionalEdge(i+1, connectedNode, weight);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString((g.getAdjacentVertexNumbers(i))));

    }
Kruskal k = new Kruskal(g);
    List<Edge> mst = k.getMSTEdges();

    System.out.println ("Minimum Spanning Tree Edges are:");
    ListIterator<Edge> it = mst.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Edge e = (Edge)it.next();
        System.out.println ("v" + e.getFrom().getVertexNo() + " --- v" + e.getTo().getVertexNo());
        }
```

### Kruskal class

```
  public class Kruskal {
private Graph graph;
private int[] sets; //represent set for vertices

public Kruskal(Graph g) {
    this.graph = g;
    this.sets = new int[g.getTotalNumberOfVertices()];
}

private void makeSet(Vertex v){
    this.sets[v.getVertexNo()] = v.getVertexNo(); //simply set the set name to each vertex no
}

private int findSet(Vertex v){
    return this.sets[v.getVertexNo()]; //gets the set name/number of a vertex
}

private void union(Vertex u, Vertex v){
    int findWhat, replaceWith;

    if(u.getVertexNo() < v.getVertexNo()){
        findWhat = this.sets[v.getVertexNo()];
        replaceWith = this.sets[u.getVertexNo()];
    }
    else{
        findWhat = this.sets[u.getVertexNo()];
        replaceWith = this.sets[v.getVertexNo()];
    }

    //make both sets same
    for(int i=0; i<this.sets.length; i++){
        if(this.sets[i] == findWhat){
            this.sets[i] = replaceWith;
        }
    }

}

private void sortEdges(Edge[] edges){
    for(int i=0; i<edges.length-1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<edges.length; j++){
            if(edges[i].getWeight() > edges[j].getWeight()){
                Edge tmp = edges[i];
                edges[i] = edges[j];
                edges[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}

//runs the main kruskal algorithm
public List<Edge> getMSTEdges(){
    //holds the MST edges
    List<Edge> mstEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();

    Vertex[] vertices = this.graph.getVertices();
    for(int i=0; i<vertices.length; i++){
        this.makeSet(vertices[i]);
    }

    //get all bi-directional edges
    Edge[] edges = this.graph.getAllBidirectionalEdges();
    //sort the edges w.r.t their weights in non-decreasing order
    this.sortEdges(edges);

    for(int i=0; i<edges.length; i++){
        //for each each, in sorted order
        Edge e = edges[i];          
        if(this.findSet(e.getFrom()) != this.findSet(e.getTo())){
            //if the vertices it connects are not in the same set
            //this edge is an MST edge
            mstEdges.add(e);
            //now, both vertices should have same set
            this.union(e.getFrom(), e.getTo());
        }
    }

    return mstEdges;
}
}
```

#### Graph class

```
public class Graph {
private final int DEFAULT_EDGE_COST = 1;
private Vertex[] vertices = null; //list of all vertices in the graph
private int totalVertices = 0; //keeps count of vertices
private int[][] adjMatrix = null; //keeps the edges of the graph using adjacency matrix
private int[] adjacentVertCount = null; //keeps count of adjacent vertices for each vertex

public Graph(int maxVertices) {
    this.vertices = new Vertex[maxVertices]; //initialize vertices array
    this.adjMatrix = new int[maxVertices][maxVertices]; //initialize adjacency matrix
    this.adjacentVertCount = new int[maxVertices]; //initialize adjacent vertices count
    for(int i=0; i<maxVertices; i++){
        this.adjacentVertCount[i] = 0; //set adjacent vertex count to 0 initially
        for(int j=0; j<maxVertices; j++){
            this.adjMatrix[i][j] = -1; //set adjacency list to -1 initially
        }
    }
}



 public Graph(){
    //default Max amount of vertices: 100 [0-99]
    this(100);
}

//add a new vertex with vertexNo and data
public void addVertex(int vertexNo, Object data){
    this.vertices[vertexNo] = new Vertex(vertexNo, data);
    this.totalVertices++;
}

//add a new vertex with vertexNo only
public void addVertex(int vertexNo){
    this.addVertex(vertexNo, null);
}

//add a uni-directional edge with cost
public void addEdge(int fromVertexNo, int toVertexNo, int cost){
    this.adjMatrix[fromVertexNo][toVertexNo] = cost;
    this.adjacentVertCount[fromVertexNo]++;
} 

//add a bi-directional edge with cost
public void addBidirectionalEdge(int vertex1, int vertex2, int cost){
    this.addEdge(vertex1, vertex2, cost);
    this.addEdge(vertex2, vertex1, cost);
}

//add a bi-directional edge with cost
public void addBidirectionalEdge(Vertex v1, Vertex v2, int cost){
    this.addBidirectionalEdge(v1.getVertexNo(), v2.getVertexNo(), cost);
}


//get the total vertices count in the graph
public int getTotalNumberOfVertices(){
    return this.totalVertices;
}



//get adjacent vertex numbers for a given vertexNo
public int[] getAdjacentVertexNumbers(int vertexNo){
    int[] ret = new int[this.adjacentVertCount[vertexNo]];
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<this.adjMatrix[vertexNo].length; i++){
        if(this.adjMatrix[vertexNo][i] >= 0){
            ret[index++] = i;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

//get adjacent vertex numbers for a given vertex
public int[] getAdjacentVertexNumbers(Vertex vert){
    return this.getAdjacentVertexNumbers(vert.getVertexNo());
}

//get adjacent vertices for a given vertexNo
public Vertex[] getAdjacentVertices(int vertexNo){
    Vertex[] ret = new Vertex[this.adjacentVertCount[vertexNo]];
    int index = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<this.adjMatrix[vertexNo].length; i++){
        if(this.adjMatrix[vertexNo][i] >= 0){
            ret[index++] = this.vertices[i];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

//get adjacent vertices for a given vertex
public Vertex[] getAdjacentVertices(Vertex vert){
    return this.getAdjacentVertices(vert.getVertexNo());
}

//gets the edge/path cost from adjacency list for two given vertexNo
public int getEdgeCost(int fromVertNo, int toVertNo){
    return this.adjMatrix[fromVertNo][toVertNo];
}

//gets the edge/path cost from adjacency list for two given vertices
public int getEdgeCost(Vertex fromVert, Vertex toVert){
    return this.getEdgeCost(fromVert.getVertexNo(), toVert.getVertexNo());
}

//gets all vertices
public Vertex[] getVertices(){
    return this.vertices;
}

//returns all the edges of the graph
//needed for edge traversing algorithms
public Edge[] getAllEdges(){
    int totalEdges = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.adjacentVertCount.length; i++){
        totalEdges += this.adjacentVertCount[i];
    }

    Edge[] edges = new Edge[totalEdges];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.vertices.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<this.vertices.length; j++){
            if(this.adjMatrix[i][j] >= 0){
                edges[index++] = new Edge(this.vertices[i], this.vertices[j], this.adjMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return edges;
}

public Edge[] getAllBidirectionalEdges(){
    int totalEdges = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.adjacentVertCount.length; i++){
        totalEdges += this.adjacentVertCount[i];
    }
    totalEdges /= 2;

    Edge[] edges = new Edge[totalEdges];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.vertices.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<this.vertices.length; j++){
            if(this.adjMatrix[i][j] >= 0){
                edges[index++] = new Edge(this.vertices[i], this.vertices[j], this.adjMatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return edges;
}

}
```

#### Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Kruskal.makeSet(Kruskal.java:15)
at Kruskal.getMSTEdges(Kruskal.java:62)
at Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

I get the edges to print out nicely however when I implement the k.getMSTEdges() if gives me null pointers and doesn't like it. 
However when I hardcode it, for example g.addBidrectionalEdge(0,2,8) and so on it works so I know its something about the main here that I'm not right on. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: show the stack trace..

Comment: Show the code where null pointer thrown and stack trace as well

Comment: It is done. I added the stack trace

Comment: show your code from Kruskal, your null pointer is coming from there it seems.

Comment: There you go! Sorry I should have added it in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be your problem:

```
for(int i=0; i<maximumVertices-1; i++)
```

Change it to

```
for(int i=0; i<maximumVertices; i++)
```

This is from where you create your graph.

Otherwise, you only create 49 vertices, and then when you try to access the 50th one, there is NULL data. Or at least, I'm assuming that Vertex initializes some data to NULL